# Layout difference report in Selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to get the report of layout difference of a particular site in different browsers(IE ,chrome,Firefox) in selenium webdriver. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `selenium` is browser automation - it mimics the real user interactions on a page: opening pages, clicking buttons, filling forms etc. Pure selenium would not handle what you are asking about - it is not what selenium was built for. You need a separate tool, that is, not necessarily, built on top of selenium.

The first thing coming into my mind is [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) and it's [*Browser Screenshots*](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots) feature:

> Browsers & Mobile Devices for Screenshots Testing BrowserStack
>   Screenshots + Responsive provide quick compatibility testing across a
>   wide array of browsers and mobile devices.

There are plenty of devices and browsers available for providing you with screenshots. Quick example:

[image]

There is an [API](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api) with different language bindings, e.g. for python:

- [pybrowserstack-screenshots](https://github.com/cmck/pybrowserstack-screenshots)

---

Another option would be to use [CSS Needle](http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package which is based on [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and [`nose`](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/):

> It checks that CSS renders correctly by taking screenshots of portions
>   of a website and comparing them against known good screenshots. It
>   also provides tools for testing calculated CSS values and the position
>   of HTML elements.

---

Also see:

- [Testing Page Layout with webdriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/testing-page-layout-with-webdriver)
- [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/)

Comment: No. I need to test it in Selenium webdriver not in tool.